# Add icons in unity quicklist?

Tags: unity, icons, quicklists

Is it possible to achieve something like this? Small icons in front of quicklist items. Would make life easier.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*To the original version of the question (although it also applies to the edited one)*

---

You can use *textual icons* from the font **Ubuntu**:

[image]

#### How to set up

1. Open Special Characters, choose the font **Ubuntu*** and make a choice of appropriate icons.
2. Copy the global `rhythmbox.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
3. Open the local copy with (e.g.) `gedit`:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications
   ```

   Now scroll to the shortcut sections, looking like:

   ```
   [Desktop Action PlayPause]
   Name=Play/Pause
   Exec=rhythmbox-client --play-pause
   ```

   Now copy the corresponding character from Sepecial Characters and edit the line `Name=Play/Pause` into: `Name=⇫ Play/Pause`. ***Don't change the other lines.***.

Edit the other shortcut sections similarly. Now log out and back in, and you're done.

---

*Other xamples from Ubuntu textual icons*

[image]

Comment: Haha nice! I never knew there is such kind of work around :)

Comment: @AlanJameson I use them a lot, it is the only escape to use icons in GTK menus :)

Comment: Thanks for this clever trick.. but is there any way to use image icons? I edited my question with picture (took from classic menu indicator)

Comment: @Edgar I am pretty sure there isn't. There is no API for that, and editing the source is not the type of sport we should do here I believe. Apart from that, the general direction is to move icons out of menus etc, making it purely textual, so I believe it won't be possible in future releases as well. I think this is as close as we can get. I updated the image though, showing that the Ubuntu font offers quite some options, just no colored ones.